# Issues in removing # from angular routes

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to preetify my URL in angular js app and remove the hash. What I did was added in line in my app.config function:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

But this issues I am still facing are:

1. If I open a page like this `$window.location.href = '#/sales';` the slash is encoded and page does not opens.
2. If I directly type in my browser `localhost:9000/sales` without hash the page does not opens.

Can someone please help.

To add to it, my base url is: `http://localhost:9000`

Answer (score 0):

You should choose just one option: either you have hashes in the url, or not.
If hashes are ok - then just remove `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` from your code.

If you really want your app to work w/o hashes in the url then follow this (probably incomplete) checklist:

1. Remove `#` from any urls on your page
2. Configure your web-server to feed the same webapp on all requests which your webapp recognizes. I.e. If your webapp routing knows what to do when user agent is requesting /sales - then make sure that your web-server or backend platform you are using serves the page with your web-app

Comment: As I already mentioned I want to get rid of hashbangs. The trouble is with angular routing, and I expect it to be able to take care of URLs with or without hash.